# Why is my javascript reduce function returns too much number when it comes to 0

Tags: javascript, reduce

With reduce function this was supposed to return 9000 but how come does it return 256000?
I tested similar code before and it worked fine

```js
function combined(...s) {
  return s.flat().reduce(x => x + x)
}

console.log(combined([1000, 1000, 1000], [1000, 1000, 1000], [1000, 1000, 1000]))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) normally takes 2 parameters, in your case `x` holds the accumulated value, and the second parameter, `y` that I added, would be the current value in the iteration. You would have to use it like this:

```js
function combined(...s){
  return s.flat().reduce((x, y) => x + y)
}

console.log(combined([1000,1000,1000],[1000,1000,1000],[1000,1000,1000]))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) callback function requires 2 parameters at least: `accumulator` and `currentValue`.

Also, you can pass an initial value to the `accumulator`, which in this case should be `0`

```js
function combined(...s){
  return s.flat().reduce((result, x) => result + x, 0)
}

console.log(combined([1000,1000,1000],[1000,1000,1000],[1000,1000,1000]))
```

In your case, the `x` stands for the `accumulator` which initialized with the first element of the array: `1000`, and you are basically returning `accumulator + accumulator`, which results in the following:

```
- 2000 (1000 + 1000)
- 4000 (2000 + 2000)
- 8000 (4000 + 4000)
...
- 256000 (128000 + 128000)
```